Is a frame of free falling observer inertial in Newtonian mechanics?
It seems to me that a frame of an observer undergoing free fall on Earth (before entering its exosphere) is not inertial in Newtonian mechanics, even though it is inertial in special and general relativity, according to this question and this physicsforums thread. I still don't fully understand why.
I am not convinced by the argument by JEB in the first link. I don't think Newton's second law is violated in the frame of free falling observer. Suppose you are inside a windowless laboratory that undergoes a free fall on Earth, holding a steel ball. Since you have no knowledge of what's outside the laboratory, you know there are no external forces. So when you release the ball, you expect it to move in straight line or remain at rest. I don't see any contradiction with Newton's second law.
Is there anything wrong with my train of thought?

So what is wrong with this JEB characters argument in the 1st link? I think an inertial frame for Newton has constant velocity in many, and zero in fewer, coordinates systems.

@JEB I am not sure why the researcher assumed gravity exists. You are saying that every inertial frame in Newtonian mechanics must move in constant velocity with respect to absolute space, right?

If newton insists on absolute space, then yes. If we're going Galilean relativity, then constant velocity. gravity is just some external force that acts at a distance and instantly (the former bothered Newton).

And by corollary, the physics classroom is emphatically not an inertial system -- middle school physics is a lot of make-belief or even cargo cult.

In Newtonian mechanics, "inertial frame" means a frame in which all free bodies move rectilinearly, close and distant, not just those close to the observer. So the observers in a free-falling spaceship, who are in a room with closed window, when observing only motions inside, might think it possible that their frame is inertial, but they still have to check what goes on outside. When they do, and make measurements that are accurate enough (not easy), they will detect the whole world (Earth, Moon, Andromeda...) is accelerating in their frame with the same acceleration, and since there is no plausible force acting on all those bodies causing this, the only correct conclusion in Newtonian scheme the observers can make is that  their frame is not inertial. In an inertial frame, highly accelerated motions have plausible explanation; e.g. the acceleration of the free-falling spaceship in the frame of Earth (but non-rotating) is explained by Newtonian gravity force, mostly due to Earth. No such explanation works for motions of distant free bodies in the frame of the freely falling observers. Fictitious forces like inertial force $-m\mathbf a$ or Coriolis force $-2m\boldsymbol{\omega}\times\mathbf v$ are not allowed to explain these motions, these are not real impressed forces in Newtonian mechanics. Notice the formulae for fictitious forces are always kinematic, they do not refer to physical state of any other body, and also these fictitious forces have no 3rd law counterpart.

Thanks. It seems like you are talking about global inertial frames, right? Since special relativity also deals with global inertial frames, free falling frames are not inertial in special relativity as well? Free falling frames are inertial in general relativity only.

@user366875 Yes, and even in GR, only locally inertial.


Since you have no knowledge of what's outside the laboratory, you know there are no external forces.

This statement must be made a little stronger in order to accomplish what you want. Mere ignorance of the presence of something is not knowledge of its absence. What you need to assert is the impossibility of knowing the laboratory’s uniform gravitational acceleration. If something cannot be known then it has no physical effect (otherwise it could be known by said effect). If there is no possible physical effect then it can be removed from the physics.
This is the heart of the equivalence principle. Although it is not explicitly stated, Newtonian gravity is consistent with the equivalence principle. This means that (although it is rarely done) Newtonian gravity can be geometrized and treated as the curvature of spacetime. This is known as Newton-Cartan gravity.
So, in principle you are correct. However, the resulting mathematical framework is unfamiliar, cumbersome, and rarely used. Thus in practice @JEB’s answer is correct.
Furthermore, if you say “Newtonian mechanics”, few people will think of Newton-Cartan gravity and fewer will include it under that umbrella. So the acceptance of the in principle answer is easily disputable. I personally tend to lump Newton-Cartan gravity in with Newtonian mechanics for the same reason I lump Lagrangian mechanics in: the math is different but the experimental predictions are the same.

So in Newtonian mechanics, a frame where you feel gravity is an inertial frame?

What do you mean by "However, the resulting mathematical framework is unfamiliar, cumbersome, and rarely used"?

I mean not many people have even seen the Newton Cartan formalism, it is mathematically even more difficult than the math for general relativity, and because it is so difficult people don’t use it for any practical computations that I am aware of.

I do think there is a problem with your train of thought. When you say "you have no knowledge of what's outside the laboratory". Newton's gravity has infinite reach (it's a force acting at a distance), and it acts instantly. So gravity:
$$ \vec F = -G\frac{Mm}{r^2}\hat r $$
is acting on the test mass. You, in the lab, also: don't stick to the floor, so you know you are falling.
Your lab is falling, which means your frame is non-inertial. The ball is falling, so it looks to be floating, but $\vec F$ is acting on it.
There's also observable tidal forces. I know we localize those away in relativity--but I don't think that's legit for Newton: if the lab is too small to see them, then you problem is in your experimental gear, it's not good enough to answer the question, and thought experiment about an apparatus that isn't good enough, is just a bad thought experiment.
